# How to exclude farm, admin, crawl etc. accounts from the people search result page?

Tags: search-results, people-search

I am using sp2013. I have a page with a search result webpart. It shows all users. It is also possible to search for a user. I see there in the results also the farm, admin etc accounts. How can I exclude them from the search results?

I have a sync configuration to AD.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the People Scope to exclude the Farm account or Admin account. To perform this action you should make the accountname a managed property which can be used in scopes and then simply add an exclusion rule for the people scope.

Or define a property in SharePoint User Profiles that can identify which are admin accounts. Once the User profiles get it into your SharePoint, you can then modify the Search Scope to add an exclude rule that remove these accounts from People Search.